# Why wont agent move to next line of text

Tags: lotusscript

I am creating an agent that will go through a list of Lotus Notes document ID's read in from a text file.  The text file holds the Document ID's line by line and there is no whitespace after each line and no extra lines after the last entry.  But my agent will only process the first line in the text file and not move onto the next line.  Why is this?

Before I coded the loop going through the view the MsgBox outputted every line.

```
Sub Initialize

 Dim viewAllContracts As NotesView
 Dim requestDoc1 As NotesDocument
 Dim filenum As Integer
 Dim filename As String
 Dim conStatus As Variant
 Dim strLineValue As String
 Dim checkId As Variant

 Set s = New NotesSession
 Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

 filenum% = FreeFile()
 filename$ = "C:\ContractIdtoComplete.txt"
 Open filename$ For Input As filenum%
 Set viewAllContracts = db.GetView("Contracts \ All By Year")
 Set requestDoc1 = viewAllContracts.GetFirstDocument

   While Not EOF(filenum%) ' Read until end of file.
     Line Input #filenum%, strLineValue$
      Do Until requestDoc1 Is Nothing
       checkId = requestDoc1.getitemvalue("conContractId")
       conStatus = requestDoc1.getitemvalue("conContractStatus")
       If strLineValue = CStr(checkId(0)) Then
         If CStr(conStatus(0)) = "Open" Then
           MsgBox "Found " & strLineValue
    Call requestDoc1.ReplaceItemValue("conContractStatus", "Completed")
    Call requestDoc1.Save(True, True)
        End If
     End If
     Set requestDoc1 = viewAllContracts.Getnextdocument(requestDoc1)
   Loop
  Wend
  Close filenum%

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first while loop your requestDoc1 is Nothing. That's why nothing happens for next lines from text file.

Put the line

```
Set requestDoc1 = viewAllContracts.GetFirstDocument
```

after line

```
Line Input #filenum%, strLineValue$
```

Then it will work for all text file lines.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error.  Quite an obvious one.  Sorry.  Thanks again